# Cython not seeing any speedup

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I have defined a very simple function ellipse_python():

```
import numpy as np
    def ellipse_python(array_of_spec_arg,coords_detection, offset_is_true=False, UF=1.):


        nrows=array_of_spec_arg.shape[0]
        Ps=np.empty(shape=(nrows,1))
        offset=0
        if offset_is_true:
            offset=3

        for i in range(0,nrows):
            list_of_spec=array_of_spec_arg[i,:]
            coords_center=np.asarray(list_of_spec[0:2])/UF

            edges_coords=np.asarray(list_of_spec[(offset+3):(offset+11)])
            X=edges_coords[0:4]
            Y=edges_coords[4:8]

            Edges=np.zeros((4,))
            Edges[0] = np.sqrt(np.square(X[0]-X[1]+1)+np.square(Y[0]-Y[1]+1))/UF
            Edges[1] = np.sqrt(np.square(X[1]-X[2]+1)+np.square(Y[1]-Y[2]+1))/UF 
            Edges[2] = np.sqrt(np.square(X[2]-X[3]+1)+np.square(Y[2]-Y[3]+1))/UF
            Edges[3] = np.sqrt(np.square(X[3]-X[0]+1)+np.square(Y[3]-Y[0]+1))/UF


            Edges.sort()
            Edges=Edges[::-1]
            W=np.mean(Edges[0:2])/2
            L=np.mean(Edges[2:4])/2
            alpha=-list_of_spec[2]
            distance=coords_detection-coords_center
            xx=distance[0]
            yy=distance[1]

            x = np.cos(alpha)*xx-np.sin(alpha)*yy;
            y = np.sin(alpha)*xx+np.cos(alpha)*yy;
            P=(np.square(x/W)+np.square(y/L))


            Ps[i]=P


        return Ps
```

I use it very often in my code making it a bottleneck for speed so I cythonized it using every trick i could find in Cython numpy tutorial.
Here is the result of my .pyx:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np




from cpython cimport bool


ctypedef np.float64_t dtype_t64
ctypedef np.float32_t dtype_t32

cimport cython
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)

def ellipse_cython(np.ndarray[dtype_t64, ndim=2] array_of_spec_arg ,np.ndarray[np.int64_t, ndim=1] coords_detection, bool offset_is_true=False, dtype_t32 UF=1.):


    cdef int nrows=array_of_spec_arg.shape[0]
    cdef np.ndarray[dtype_t64,ndim=2] Ps=np.empty(shape=(nrows,1))
    cdef int offset=0        
    cdef np.ndarray[dtype_t64, ndim=1] list_of_spec 
    cdef np.ndarray[dtype_t64, ndim=1] coords_center
    cdef np.ndarray[dtype_t64, ndim=1] edges_coords
    cdef np.ndarray[dtype_t64, ndim=1] X
    cdef np.ndarray[dtype_t64, ndim=1] Y
    cdef np.ndarray[dtype_t64, ndim=1] Edges=np.zeros((4,))
    cdef dtype_t32 W
    cdef dtype_t32 L
    cdef dtype_t32 alpha
    cdef np.ndarray[dtype_t64, ndim=1] distance
    cdef dtype_t32 xx
    cdef dtype_t32 yy
    cdef dtype_t32 x
    cdef dtype_t32 y
    cdef dtype_t32 P

    if offset_is_true:
        offset=3

    for i in xrange(nrows):
        list_of_spec=array_of_spec_arg[i,:]
        coords_center=np.asarray(list_of_spec[0:2])/UF    
        edges_coords=np.asarray(list_of_spec[(offset+3):(offset+11)])
        X=edges_coords[0:4]
        Y=edges_coords[4:8]


        Edges[0] = np.sqrt(np.square(X[0]-X[1]+1)+np.square(Y[0]-Y[1]+1))/UF
        Edges[1] = np.sqrt(np.square(X[1]-X[2]+1)+np.square(Y[1]-Y[2]+1))/UF 
        Edges[2] = np.sqrt(np.square(X[2]-X[3]+1)+np.square(Y[2]-Y[3]+1))/UF
        Edges[3] = np.sqrt(np.square(X[3]-X[0]+1)+np.square(Y[3]-Y[0]+1))/UF


        Edges.sort()
        Edges=Edges[::-1]
        W=np.mean(Edges[0:2])/2.
        L=np.mean(Edges[2:4])/2.
        alpha=-list_of_spec[2]
        distance=coords_detection-coords_center
        xx=distance[0]
        yy=distance[1]

        x = np.cos(alpha)*xx-np.sin(alpha)*yy;
        y = np.sin(alpha)*xx+np.cos(alpha)*yy;
        P=(np.square(x/W)+np.square(y/L))


        Ps[i]=P


    return Ps
```

As you can see every type is specified and every check is disabled.
However when I time both function I do not get any speed-up.
import numpy as np

```
import ellipse_cython
import ellipse_python
width=45
cropped_window_centers=np.random.randint(width+1,1024-(width+1),(10,2))
array_of_spec=np.array([[34.372817, 220.59854,-1.496308,    1.  , 1. ,0.,26., 45., 39.,27., 203.,204.,240.,234.],[  34.811641,269.966265,   -1.558297,    1.  ,1.,0. ,26.,44.,43. ,26., 249.,251.,293.,287.]])
%timeit -n2 -r10 ellipse_python.ellipse_python(array_of_spec,cropped_window_centers[0], True, 4.)
%timeit -n2 -r10 ellipse_cython.ellipse_cython(array_of_spec,cropped_window_centers[0], True, 4.)


2 loops, best of 10: 2.42 ms per loop
2 loops, best of 10: 2.42 ms per loop
```

Am I doing this right ? Is there something that could be done to improve speed ? Or should I be happy with what I got from numpy.

Comment: I understand that numpy is a C library I am just asking to be sure that I did everything I could

Comment: At a quick glance, the computation itself is already quite optimised from numpy, and i think the bottleneck comes from the "loop" `for i in xrange(...)`.  One suggestion is to use `threading` and put **Ps** as a global dict and perform the for loop in a concurrent manner.

Comment: Thanks for answering Anzel I also thought it was the case but as it is my first time using Cython I want to be sure. Also I understood about doing it concurrently with multiple threads in the for loop but I do not understand the global dict part ? Could you expand a bit on that ?

Comment: You mean to replace Ps by a dictionnary of numpy arrays instead of a numpy array ? And define it in a global way inside the function ? Why would it improve the situation ?

Comment: the reason it takes some time is due to each loop is "blocking" until computation is done. and it will be easier to assign result from each loop to a `dict[i]` in a concurrent manner, so you can complete all the loops in a shorter time. and at end of the function just reconstruct the np array from the dict

Comment: Where you're working on single elements (e.g. your square roots) use `sqrt` from `libc.math` instead of numpy. Similarly the `np.square` should probably just be replaced by a manual square `(X[0]-X[1]+1)*(X[0]-X[1]+1)`. These are Python function calls and they take time.

Comment: Also use `sin` and `cos` from `libc.math` if you're working on single numbers.

Comment: You should probably also replace `np.mean`s with just adding the two elements yourself and dividing by 2.

Comment: Thanks duly noted !

Comment: I did what you said the speed-up is quite nice ! x4 ! However it seems that sin and cos in libc and numpy are not exactly the same !

Comment: And not using any thread ! (it also seems that the mean function in numpy is slightly different than taking the mean yourself not sure why investigating)

Comment: Not being exactly the same is probably because the c math library works on doubles so there's a conversation to double and back. Provided it's only in the last few decimal places it's not worth worrying about.

Comment: Your only iteration is over this `array_of_spec`, and in the test there are only 2 of those.  `cython` gives the best improvement when it streamlines a large iteration with a simple task.

Comment: Yeah ok great the greatest speed up I got came from using libc.math and not numpy I guess both of you guys are right.

Comment: For small stuff lists and scalars are faster than arrays.  You aren't making serious use of `numpy` arrays or functions.  The `edges` calculation could be expressed in array form, but it's only a 4 element array; not worth the overhead.